# UITableViewCell with UISwitch causes .tag = 1 to become null

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have a custom tableview with 6 rows. 5 rows have UITextFields in them, and 1 row has a UISwitch in it.

I add the textboxes like this:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                txtLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Name:", @"");
                txtField.tag=1;
                [txtField becomeFirstResponder];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:txtField];
                [txtField release];
                break;
```

in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

The switch is added like:

```
case 3:
                txtLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Male:", @"");
                UISwitch *mySwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
                cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
                [mySwitch setTag:6];
                break;
```

I read the values in another method like:

```
UITextField *daName = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

But for some reason, as soon as I add the UISwitch, the daName value becomes null. The other values are read well (so tag 2 is ok, tag 3 is ok etc.)

What am I missing here? Because when I remove the UISwitch then I get a value back from tag 1...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I just see that as soon as I have 6 rows in my tableview the element with tag id 1 gets null... As soon as I have 5 rows, I can get all values...

Comment: How many rows display at once, even partially?

Comment: The table has now 6 rows, 5 with a label and a UITextView and 1 with a label and a UISwitch. They show all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've added a mutablearray and added the textfields into the array. That way I don't have to use the tag anymore and that is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I did read somewhere on stackoverflow that you shouldn't use 0 or 1 when you set tags, I can't remember where, but I think it mentioned something about default? might be worth a search...

Comment: I've tried that, also using tag id's starting from 100 but the same result.. Thanks for your reply do!

Comment: it's just 0 that you shouldn't use, because zero is the default tag for all views. ie every view that doesn't have a tag explicitly set has a tag of 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
 UISwitch *daName = (UISwitch *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];

 if (daName.on){
  // handle the switch of particular of tag 


}
```